Simulate photodiode in ltspice
I am trying to simulate a photodiode output in LTSpice. I was wondering if it is possible to have an independent current source wave that goes up to xyz uA (min 0 uA and max xyz uA) with a rise and fall time of xyz with an xyz frequency. xyz is a placeholder because I do not have the values of these yet.

Yes, it's absolutely possible. Use an independent current source, select "PULSE", enter initial current (maybe your dark current), pulse current, delay time, rise time, fall time, on time, period and number of cycles.
You can also use a piecewise linear source or a TABLE if the PULSE isn't what you're looking for.
You can add a capacitor across the source to model the diode capacitance at whatever bias condition your circuit uses.
